# Representing Flats Within a Block?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a list of 18 properties, which are all flats. They are split between 3 blocks, 6 flats each.
Therefore there are 6 points with the same co ordinates, but each of the flats has their own attributes.

[image: Block 2 - 6]

In number “Block 2”, two of the six flats have different attributes to the other four.
(e.g. different number of bedrooms per flat)
When I use the symbology tool within the Layer Properties to show the differences within,  it is only going to show me whichever is on top.

I would like to find a way to represent this?

I know I could move these manually, but with the amount of properties I am going to have to do this to it is not the way forward.

Using: Arcmap 10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this [Disperse Markers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Disperse_Markers/00700000002n000000/) tool to separate the points by a small distance. There are options for a random pattern or expansion, rings around the central point etc. This is a cartographic representation.